# PhoneGap for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, cordova

I'm interested in developing applications for windows phone 7 with the PhoneGap. I know that there may not have an official version of PhoneGap for windows mobile yet, but I tried to run two projects, but got errors when implementing them.

- 1st project: https://github.com/filmaj/phonegap-winphone
- 2nd project: https://github.com/mrlacey/phonegap-wp7

**Errors:**

- *1st application:*

Warning message!

You are using a project created by previous version of Windows Phone Developer Tools CTP. Your application may not run properly.

Please edit the WMAppManifest.xml file under Properties node and insert the following  elements between  element as shown below.

```
<Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
</Capabilities>
```

- After inserting those fields, i got many errors on "Errors list".
- *2nd application*

output message:

C:\Users...\mrlacey-phonegap-wp7-1dcce5b\WP7Gap\WP7Gap\WP7Gap.csproj : error  : Unable to read the project file 'WP7Gap.csproj'.

C:\Users...\mrlacey-phonegap-wp7-1dcce5b\WP7Gap\WP7Gap\WP7Gap.csproj(135,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight for Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.WindowsPhone71.Overrides.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-wp7

Please note that this is still not really production ready yet though.
We're hoping that it will be there by the time Mango launches though.

Note that this is targetting the Mango beta 2 refresh. I'd assume that you're not using that.

The one you got from my site looks like a very old version. Get the latest version.

I've updated my github profile so you can contact me through there now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I downloaded the Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools from http://phone.microsoftplatformready.com/Dashboard.aspx but I have a file called microsoft.silverlight.windowsphone.overrides.targets instead of microsoft.silverlight.windowsphone71.overrides.targets. Do I have to uninstall anything before I install the files you suggest or can I install over the top of them?

Comment: Or could I just rename the file??

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'm okay. I found this http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-install-Windows-Phone-Developer-Tools-7-1-Beta-Mango which says what to do (although the download link was broken, I found vm_web2.exe here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27570)

Comment: Also for anyone else having trouble getting the latest versions of everything, as it wasn't immediately obvious to me (despite it being right in front of my face) phonegap-wp7 moved locations to https://github.com/callback/phonegap

Answer (score 0):

For the record :)

Use the latest lib of phonegap for WP7 from:

https://github.com/callback/phonegap/tree/master/lib/windows